# Too many levels of nesting for IF function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using together with "IF" and "filler" function to look for result, but it is just too complex.

Is it possible to reformulate formula below earlier and write into one cell?

Thanks in advance!

```
J33=IF(I33=A33,1,IF(I33=A32,2,IF(I33=A31,3,IF(I33=A30,4,IF(I33=A29,5,IF(I33=A28,6,IF(I33=A27,7,IF(I33=A26,8,"*")))))))) =IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET(J33,-J33-1,0)),"Y","")
```

```
K33=IF(K33="Y",IF(ISBLANK(B30),"R1",IF(ISBLANK(B29),"R2",IF(ISBLANK(B28),"R3",IF(ISBLANK(B27),"R4",IF(ISBLANK(B26),"R5",IF(ISBLANK(B25),"R6","R")))))),"")
```

```
M33=IF(L33="error",IF(ISBLANK(B24),"R7",IF(ISBLANK(B23),"R8",IF(ISBLANK(B22),"R9",IF(ISBLANK(B21),"R10","error")))),"")
```

```
Q33=IF(L33="Error","",IF(L33="R2",CONCATENATE(B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R3",CONCATENATE(B29," ",B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R4",CONCATENATE(B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R5",CONCATENATE(B27," ",B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),"Error")))))&IF(M33="Error","",IF(L33="R6",CONCATENATE(B26," ",B27," ",B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R7",CONCATENATE(B25," ",B26," ",B27," ",B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R8",CONCATENATE(B24," ",B25," ",B26," ",B27," ",B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R9",CONCATENATE(B23," ",B24," ",B25," ",B26," ",B27," ",B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R10",CONCATENATE(B22," ",B23," ",B24," ",B25," ",B26," ",B27," ",B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),IF(L33="R11",CONCATENATE(B21," ",B22," ",B23," ",B24," ",B25," ",B26," ",B27," ",B28," ",B29," ",B30," ",B31),"Error")))))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser ,, plz [edit] your post and share some sample data, will help us to understand the situation,,,

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, cannot add comments, but change `jlear's` `MATCH()` function to `XMATCH()` and use the last option in it (set to `-1`) to search the range last-to-first. That will restore your test sequence.

One of the advantages to `XMATCH()` in a case of a new function not immediately blowing one's skirt up. Very helpful here.

Comment: Forgot about the new xmatch function.  It's definitely the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IFS to simplify some of these functions.  E.g.

```
=IFS(I33=A33,1,I33=A32,2,I33=A31,3,I33=A30,4,I33=A29,5,I33=A28,6,I33=A27,7,I33=A26,8,true,"*")
```

But in the first formula it looks like you are searching for a matching item in an array.  Consider using the xmatch function for that.

```
=IFNA(9-XMATCH(I33,A26:a33,0,-1),"*")
```

The XMATCH function returns N/A if it can't find an exact match, otherwise it returns the index into the array of the match.  The third parameter, 0, indicates the match must be exact, and the fourth, -1, indicates searching in reverse order.

The IFNA checks if the 9-MATCH value is N/A.  If so, it returns "*".  If not, it returns the 9-XMATCH value.

---- edited to use XMATCH instead of MATCH per Jeorje's suggestion ----

Comment: This is good, but I think the match function as written inverts the order of the nested ifs. I haven't thought of a way to address this issue.

Comment: Ah yes.  Jeorje's xmatch answer is the better choice for reverse searches.